# PHP not writing into file. Just appending a 0 (zero)

Tags: php, file-io, fwrite

When I use the following code to append a string to a file it does nothing but to append a zero.

I can assure that the cookie is set properly as I used an if condition to check and then I do this to write the fule:

```
$file = 'leaderboard.txt';
$txt = "" + $_COOKIE["user"] + "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $txt, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

I tried this also :

```
$myfile2 = fopen("leaderboard.txt", "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "" + $_COOKIE["user"] + "\n";
fwrite($myfile2, $txt);
```

None of the methods anything but to append a `0` to the file.

Comment: change all `+` to `.`

Comment: where should i change...?

Comment: `$txt="" . $_COOKIE["user"] . "\n";`

Comment: Learn basic PHP syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php  `+` is mathematical addition. `.` is the string concatenation operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand the `0` output, you have to realize that PHP does implicit type casting which can lead to weird unexpected behavior. Since you were using a math operator, namely `+`, instead of the string concatenation operator `.`, the the strings were all cast into a number, which in your case always was zero instead of throwing an error.

But just for the fun of it try

```
echo 5 + "3 beers"
```

It will result in `8`, as the string is cast to the integer three.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$file='leaderboard.txt';
$txt=$_COOKIE["user"] . "\n";
file_put_contents($file, $txt, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

`+` is addition and `.` is used for concatenation.